# Cannot find symbol Variable SEND_SMS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to send a Sms from an android app, wrote following code but I'm getting compilation error : "Cannot find symbol Variable SEND_SMS". I have also imported "android.Manifest.permission" but not resolved. Please help me.

case R.id.SendSMS:

```
            // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

                    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                    // result of the request.
                }
            }
            try {

               SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
               smsManager.sendTextMessage(diaryEntry.getText().toString(),
                        null, diaryEntry.getText().toString(),
                        null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms has successfully sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your sms has failed...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


Build.gradle dependencies:



android {

    compileSdkVersion 23

    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "amana.loginapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}

AndroidManifest file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="amana.loginapp">

    <!-- Send SMS permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6):

**I resolved that problem with this**

```
android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;
```

**instead of**

```
Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import android.Manifest;
...
String p = Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;
```

Comment: Thanks. By making this making, this error is resolved. But, I'm also getting another error : "Cannot find symbol Variable MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS". I forgot to add this error in my initial post.

Comment: `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS` does not seem to be contained in the Android API. I guess that is a constant defined in the program itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, it is a constant defined in the program.

Comment: So what is the conclusion is that post the answer @Henry